# What does "viewport has zero dimensions" mean in check_model function in the performance package for R?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

### Data for Question

Here is my data:

```
structure(list(Mins_Work = c(435L, 350L, 145L, 135L, 15L, 60L, 
60L, 390L, 395L, 395L, 315L, 80L, 580L, 175L, 545L, 230L, 435L, 
370L, 255L, 515L, 330L, 65L, 115L, 550L, 420L, 45L, 266L, 196L, 
198L, 220L, 17L, 382L, 0L, 180L, 343L, 207L, 263L, 332L, 259L, 
417L, 282L, 685L, 517L, 111L, 64L, 466L, 499L, 460L, 269L, 300L, 
427L, 301L, 436L, 342L, 229L, 379L, 102L, 146L, 94L, 345L, 73L, 
204L, 512L, 113L, 135L, 458L, 493L, 552L, 108L, 335L, 395L, 508L, 
546L, 396L, 159L, 325L, 747L, 650L, 377L, 461L, 669L, 186L, 220L, 
410L, 708L, 409L, 515L, 413L, 166L, 451L, 660L, 177L, 192L, 191L, 
461L, 637L, 297L, 601L, 586L, 270L, 479L, 480L, 397L, 174L, 111L, 
0L, 610L, 332L, 345L, 423L, 160L, 611L, 345L, 550L, 324L, 427L, 
505L, 632L, 560L, 230L, 495L, 235L, 522L, 654L, 465L, 377L, 260L, 
572L, 612L, 594L, 624L, 237L, 38L, 409L, 634L, 292L, 706L, 399L, 
568L, 694L, 298L, 616L, 553L, 581L, 423L, 636L, 623L, 338L, 345L, 
521L, 438L, 504L, 600L, 616L, 656L, 285L, 474L, 688L, 278L, 383L, 
535L, 363L, 470L, 457L, 303L, 123L, 363L, 329L, 513L, 636L, 421L, 
220L, 430L, 428L, 536L, 156L, 615L, 429L, 103L, 332L, 250L, 281L, 
248L, 435L, 589L, 515L, 158L, 649L, 427L, 193L, 225L, 280L, 163L, 
536L, 301L, 406L, 230L, 519L, 303L, 472L, 392L, 326L, 368L, 405L, 
515L, 308L, 259L, 769L, 93L, 517L, 261L, 420L, 248L, 265L, 834L, 
313L, 131L, 298L, 134L, 385L, 648L, 529L, 487L, 533L, 641L, 429L, 
339L, 508L, 560L, 439L, 381L, 397L, 692L, 534L, 148L, 366L, 167L, 
425L, 476L, 384L, 498L, 502L, 308L, 360L, 203L, 410L, 626L, 593L, 
409L, 531L, 157L, 357L, 443L, 615L, 564L, 341L, 352L, 609L, 686L, 
386L, 323L, 362L, 597L, 325L, 51L, 570L, 579L, 284L, 530L, 171L, 
640L, 263L, 112L, 217L, 152L, 203L, 394L, 135L, 234L, 507L, 224L, 
174L, 210L, 138L, 52L, 326L, 413L, 695L, 370L, 256L, 327L, 490L, 
128L, 469L, 567L, 359L, 561L, 478L, 233L, 550L, 390L, 406L, 56L, 
47L, 258L, 332L, 114L), Coffee_Cups = c(3L, 0L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
0L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
6L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 
3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 
7L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 
6L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
6L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 
6L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
3L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 
6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 
7L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 6L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 
3L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L), Start_Work = c(1015L, 
1000L, 945L, 1400L, 1500L, 915L, 930L, 1000L, 940L, 840L, 730L, 
1700L, 945L, 1040L, 955L, 945L, 930L, 745L, 800L, 955L, 1030L, 
1115L, 905L, 930L, 815L, 830L, 950L, 1108L, 1430L, 955L, 1313L, 
1125L, 1636L, 1126L, 1027L, 1323L, 1003L, 918L, 950L, 913L, 1244L, 
656L, 930L, 718L, 1744L, 759L, 928L, 912L, 857L, 930L, 907L, 
920L, 1029L, 1027L, 1211L, 914L, 1226L, 1337L, 1900L, 1313L, 
1118L, 800L, 700L, 1544L, 1350L, 905L, 1025L, 0L, 942L, 930L, 
1234L, 1222L, 925L, 0L, 2018L, 945L, 500L, 447L, 0L, 818L, 604L, 
632L, 1015L, 930L, 748L, 732L, 900L, 739L, 848L, 957L, 930L, 
1144L, 627L, 1200L, 825L, 624L, 736L, 846L, 1119L, 933L, 937L, 
631L, 1319L, 931L, 1019L, 2141L, 900L, 820L, 920L, 925L, 619L, 
917L, 1413L, 1014L, 910L, 1300L, 947L, 0L, 825L, 956L, 926L, 
1057L, 959L, 1056L, 1243L, 1147L, 1541L, 945L, 800L, 806L, 1000L, 
816L, 1619L, 806L, 745L, 540L, 710L, 800L, 446L, 926L, 758L, 
930L, 812L, 718L, 0L, 750L, 619L, 1134L, 1206L, 221L, 816L, 726L, 
924L, 850L, 513L, 915L, 800L, 858L, 444L, 807L, 703L, 658L, 1004L, 
700L, 700L, 1015L, 1011L, 1028L, 910L, 822L, 843L, 1052L, 901L, 
700L, 1047L, 802L, 900L, 807L, 2209L, 0L, 930L, 1014L, 842L, 
312L, 824L, 938L, 930L, 813L, 854L, 907L, 715L, 1137L, 1404L, 
942L, 830L, 1152L, 900L, 1017L, 1218L, 1017L, 642L, 832L, 700L, 
838L, 940L, 1300L, 829L, 950L, 848L, 818L, 650L, 1001L, 900L, 
813L, 830L, 746L, 828L, 828L, 751L, 853L, 419L, 517L, 1221L, 
800L, 808L, 747L, 1049L, 606L, 1005L, 958L, 843L, 856L, 0L, 744L, 
1630L, 715L, 1629L, 648L, 657L, 718L, 840L, 711L, 944L, 933L, 
744L, 913L, 750L, 818L, 1048L, 102L, 754L, 1050L, 817L, 728L, 
719L, 643L, 805L, 738L, 738L, 921L, 1200L, 738L, 743L, 704L, 
1725L, 741L, 628L, 447L, 747L, 711L, 601L, 806L, 918L, 921L, 
1015L, 608L, 1149L, 1021L, 641L, 630L, 801L, 805L, 844L, 850L, 
641L, 640L, 736L, 816L, 702L, 533L, 902L, 829L, 628L, 720L, 703L, 
713L, 1100L, 634L, 714L, 906L, 709L, 750L, 645L, 740L, 1005L, 
657L, 1012L), Day_Name = c("Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Saturday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
"Sunday", "Monday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Saturday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-307L))
```

### Problem

I have fit a linear mixed effects model with the following code:

```
library(lmerTest)
library(performance)
fit.work <- lmer(Mins_Work ~ Coffee_Cups + Start_Work +
                   (1|Day_Name),
                 data = slack.work)
```

When I try to run the `check_model` function:

```
check_model(fit.work)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in grid.Call(C_convert, x, as.integer(whatfrom), as.integer(whatto),  : 
  Viewport has zero dimension(s)
```

However if I save `check_model(fit.work)` as an object `check.fit` and run the operators for the object (such as `check.fit$PP_CHECK`), I have no issues running the plots. What is causing this error? I tried searching for this error but the pages I landed on seemed to not have real info on what was causing this. My best guess is that the plotting window is having issues with fitting all the plots into my plot viewer, but I'm not sure how to fix that.

### Edit

I tried fixing the issue by following the advice below and changing the data.

```
slack.work.fixed <- as.data.frame(slack.work)
fit.work <- lmer(Mins_Work ~ Coffee_Cups + Start_Work +
                   (1|Day_Name),
                 data = slack.work.fixed)
```

However this gives me a new error:

```
Error: The RStudio 'Plots' window
  is too small to show this
  set of plots.
  Please make the window
  larger.
```

No matter how much I maximize the size of my plot window in RStudio, it doesn't do much to fix the issue.
check_model(fit.work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't sure what the remedy was in the last answer, so I've found a simple workaround that at least suits my needs. First, I saved the `check_model` as an object:

```
#### Save Checks Into Object ####
check <- check_model(fit.work)
```

To manually pull the data out, I just used the normal `$` operators for pulling variables out:

```
#### Manually Check Data ####
check$OUTLIERS
```

For example:

```
OK: No outliers detected.
```

Then manually plotted them with the base R `plot` function like so:

```
#### Manually Plot ####
plot(check$OUTLIERS)
plot(check$PP_CHECK)
```

[image]

[image]

The individual `check` functions like `check_outliers` also allow for easy plotting of these functions whereas the base `check_model` function tries to do too much with the plot window.

Answer (score 0):

In `check_model`, there is `check_model.default`.

```
check_model.default <- function(x,
                                dot_size = 2,
                                line_size = .8,
                                panel = TRUE,
                                check = "all",
                                alpha = .2,
                                dot_alpha = .8,
                                colors = c("#3aaf85", "#1b6ca8", "#cd201f"),
                                theme = "see::theme_lucid",
                                detrend = FALSE,
                                verbose = TRUE,
                                ...) {
  # check model formula
  if (verbose) {
    insight::formula_ok(x)
  }
  
  minfo <- insight::model_info(x, verbose = FALSE)
  
  if (minfo$is_bayesian) {
    ca <- suppressWarnings(.check_assumptions_stan(x))
  } else if (minfo$is_linear) {
    ca <- suppressWarnings(.check_assumptions_linear(x, minfo))
  } else {
    ca <- suppressWarnings(.check_assumptions_glm(x, minfo))
  }
  # else {
  #   stop(paste0("`check_assumptions()` not implemented for models of class '", class(x)[1], "' yet."), call. = FALSE)
  # }
  
  attr(ca, "panel") <- panel
  attr(ca, "dot_size") <- dot_size
  attr(ca, "line_size") <- line_size
  attr(ca, "check") <- check
  attr(ca, "alpha") <- alpha
  attr(ca, "dot_alpha") <- dot_alpha
  attr(ca, "detrend") <- detrend
  attr(ca, "colors") <- colors
  attr(ca, "theme") <- theme
  attr(ca, "model_info") <- minfo
  attr(ca, "overdisp_type") <- list(...)$plot_type
  ca
}
```

With your model, error occurs in `.check_assumptions_linear` first.

```
.check_assumptions_linear <- function(model, model_info) {
  dat <- list()
  
  dat$VIF <- .diag_vif(model)
  dat$QQ <- .diag_qq(model)
  dat$REQQ <- .diag_reqq(model, level = .95, model_info = model_info)
  dat$NORM <- .diag_norm(model)
  dat$NCV <- .diag_ncv(model)
  dat$HOMOGENEITY <- .diag_homogeneity(model)
  dat$OUTLIERS <- check_outliers(model, method = "cook")
  if (!is.null(dat$OUTLIERS)) {
    threshold <- attributes(dat$OUTLIERS)$threshold$cook
  } else {
    threshold <- NULL
  }
  dat$INFLUENTIAL <- .influential_obs(model, threshold = threshold)
  dat$PP_CHECK <- tryCatch(check_predictions(model), error = function(e) NULL)
  
  dat <- insight::compact_list(dat)
  class(dat) <- c("check_model", "see_check_model")
  dat
}
```

In `.check_assumptions_linear`, error occurs in `.diag_vif`. It seems it works for other `.diag_...`s.

```
.diag_vif <- function(model) {
  out <- check_collinearity(model)
  dat <- insight::compact_list(out)
  if (is.null(dat)) {
    return(NULL)
  }
  dat$group <- "low"
  dat$group[dat$VIF >= 5 & dat$VIF < 10] <- "moderate"
  dat$group[dat$VIF >= 10] <- "high"
  
  dat <- datawizard::data_rename(
    dat,
    c("Term", "VIF", "SE_factor", "Component"),
    c("x", "y", "se", "facet")
  )
  
  dat <- datawizard::data_select(dat, c("x", "y", "facet", "group"))
  
  if (insight::n_unique(dat$facet) <= 1) {
    dat$facet <- NULL
  }
  
  attr(dat, "CI") <- attributes(out)$CI
  dat
}
```

In `.diag_vif`, error occurs in `datawizard::data_rename` part.

It works till

```
out <- check_collinearity(model)
dat <- insight::compact_list(out)
if (is.null(dat)) {
  return(NULL)
}
dat$group <- "low"
dat$group[dat$VIF >= 5 & dat$VIF < 10] <- "moderate"
dat$group[dat$VIF >= 10] <- "high"
```

where `dat` is

```
Low Correlation

        Term  VIF      VIF  CI Increased SE Tolerance Tolerance  CI group
 Coffee_Cups 1.04 [1.00, 1.85]         1.02      0.96  [0.54, 1.00]   low
  Start_Work 1.04 [1.00, 1.85]         1.02      0.96  [0.54, 1.00]   low
Warning message:
In length(other == 1) && paste0(other, "_CI") %in% colnames(x) :
  'length(x) = 2 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

then error in

```
dat <- datawizard::data_rename(
  dat,
  c("Term", "VIF", "SE_factor", "Component"),
  c("x", "y", "se", "facet")
)

Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = `*vtmp*`) : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

It's weird that if we check `names(dat)`, we can see

```
[1] "Term"              "VIF"               "VIF_CI_low"        "VIF_CI_high"      
[5] "SE_factor"         "Tolerance"         "Tolerance_CI_low"  "Tolerance_CI_high"
[9] "group"
```

but there is no `"SE_factor", "Component"` when we view `dat`

We can remove this error using `as.data.frame(dat)` instead of `dat` in `datawizard::data_rename`

Then, next error occurs when

```
class(dat) <- c("check_model", "see_check_model")
```

If we remove this part from `.check_assumptions_linear` and try `check_model.default(fit.work)`, the function gives proper result, plotting `$PP_CHECK` things with it's other components.

You may find it's source codes in

[check_model](https://github.com/easystats/performance/blob/main/R/check_model.R),
[check_model_diagostics](https://github.com/easystats/performance/blob/main/R/check_model_diagnostics.R), and [check_outliers](https://rdrr.io/cran/performance/src/R/check_outliers.R)

Comment: I'm confused...what was the actual answer you were trying to provide? It seems buried in a lot of the breakdown of the function I guess, but I'm not understanding in plain English what I'm supposed to do about it.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand I'm sorry that I made you confusing. I was not sure if you want the reason why(where) that function prints error or how to resolve that error.
To make it simple, change `dat` to `as.data.frame(dat)` in `.diag_vif` function, and remove `class(dat) <- c("check_model", "see_check_model")` part in `.check_assumptions_linear` part.

Comment: I forgot to return to this question. I have edited my question after trying what you mentioned, but I wasn't having any success.